# Removing a child from Firebase Database not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I'm trying to remove a child from firebase. Here is what I got

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let taskToDelete = groupTask[indexPath.row]

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        groupTask.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        DataService.instance.REF_GROUPS.child("task").child(taskToDelete.id).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, refer) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print(refer)
                print("Removed Correctly")
            }
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It's printing "Removed Correctly" to the console but the child is not removed in firebase. Is there another way to do it? Thank you in advance.

Firebase data structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it and it confirmed my suspicion, error is nil even if the request fails. Your first task is to ensure that the child id you're trying to delete does exist (*i.e. you are providing the correct id). This seems to be a bug in firebase. Nevertheless when using correct path I have no issue deleting the node.

To check open firebase console and find database menu inside your project. Then open whatever node is REF_GROUPS and inside you should see "child" and inside that the ids. If this is not what you see then you need to adjust the query to reflect the structure in Firebase.

**Edit**
Did not see your screenshot, based on that your query is definitely wrong. You need to

```
DataService.instance.REF_GROUPS.child("your group id comes here").child("task").child(taskToDelete.id)
```

try printing the reference and you should get

```
https://yourappname.firebaseio.com/groups/-KzVm.../task/-KZvp...
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanx